# find the function f(r)

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

If 
$$W(r)= \frac{2r+1}{r(r+1)}$$
Express $W$ in the form
$$W(r)= f(r) - f(r+1)$$

I tried doing this with partial factors but ended up in getting the + sign instead of -

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:
$$ W(r)=\frac{2r+1}{r(r+1)}=\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r+1}=f(r)-f(r+1)\tag{1} $$
it follows that:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r+1}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{N}\left(f(r)-f(r+1)\right)=f(1)-f(N+1)\tag{2} $$
and since we are free to assume $f(1)=0$, we have:
$$ f(N+1)=-\sum_{r=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r+1}\right)=-\frac{H_N+H_{N+1}}{2} \tag{3}$$
so:
$$ f(N) = \color{red}{-\frac{H_{N-1}+H_N}{2}}.\tag{4}$$